# Update field in linked table in firebird

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird

I have two tables - card and journal. The card's id (code) is a linker in journal(card-code) 
.One card can have many journals and I need to update a field(time) in this card table from journal with trigger - I have wrote the current trigger but it has errors.Please help me to locate it.

```
 AS
 DECLARE VARIABLE currentTimeOfChanging timestamp;
begin
 select current_timestamp from rdb$database into currentTimeOfChanging;

 update card
 set card.lastupdate = currentTimeOfChanging;//!error
 where card.code = journal.cardcode
end
```

Comment: Compiler said that there is an unknown token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SetLastUpdateTS FOR journal
ACTIVE AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE card SET lastupdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE code = NEW.cardcode;
END
```

Some comments:

- you don't need the `currentTimeOfChanging` temp variable, you can use the `current_timestamp` directly in the `UPDATE` statement;
- you have to prefix the variables with ":" and there is no ";" after the variable in the UPDATE statement in the PSQL code. So your original statement should have been

  update card set card.lastupdate = :currentTimeOfChanging where ...
- instead of `journal.cardcode` you use `NEW` and/or `OLD` context variables to refer the values of the current statement (which triggered the trigger).